# Read delimited file with separator and quote as the same quote character - "

Tags: r, csv, separator, read.csv

I have a CSV file where the separator is `"`

However, there are also several text variables in the file which have `" "` around the text "example".

Therefore, read.csv does not give the proper output, it says there are more columns than column names . How can I make sure that the `" "` around text is not read as a separator in R?

The file has over 4000 rows.
This is an example of what the csv looks like:

```
year"prak"pat"pres"ats"ispc"omschr
2011"724"22989865"11jun2019""V9JAA""111230""MYCINE"
2011"689"1231223"21jun2019""KA0097""288900""XACINE"
2011"661"87987987"22mar2019""J09L91""2232600""XACINE"
2011"724"22989865"11jun2019""V9JAA""111230""MYCINE"
```

I tried to use `quote = '"'` to make sure `"` around a text was not read as separator. This did not work.

I also tried `header = False`. This makes the data very messy, a lot of empty new columns.

Thank you!

Edit:

I have a similar problem for another file. The solution below unfortunately does not work for that yet.

```
year"prak"pat"pres"ats"ispc""rec"recept"freq"tij"aant"dos"freq2"tijd2"aant2"dos2"freq3"tijd3"aant3"dos3"totaalh"sterkte"ac_omschr
2019"524"223156465"25may2019""J0225C04""19465400"4"16549708""3"""D"""1"""T""""""""""""""""""""""""""20""20MG"""ICILLINE"
2019"514"28454654"26oct2019""J078AED""0"4"15915578""2"""D"""1"""T""""""""""""""""""""""""""10""20MG"""FLOXACINE"
2019"324"2845885"09jun2019""JMA4402""0"4"14798711664""2"""D"""1"""T""""""""""""""""""""""""""12""20MG"""FLOXACINE"
```

Comment: I added extra rows and the header

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer but something like `data.table::fread(cmd = 'sed -r \'s/[""]{1,3}/,/g\' messy_text.txt')` should get you most of the way there. You may have to play around with the replacement pattern a little.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to turn all double quotes to single quotes and then parse them:

```
l1 <- gsub('"{2,}', '"', readLines("test.data")) # turn all double quotes to single quotes
l2 <- gsub('|"$|^"', '', l1) # remove leading and trailing quotes

d <- read.csv(text=l2, sep='"')
```

Data then looks like this:

```
> d
  year prak      pat      pres    ats    ispc omschr
1 2011  724 22989865 11jun2019  V9JAA  111230 MYCINE
2 2011  689  1231223 21jun2019 KA0097  288900 XACINE
3 2011  661 87987987 22mar2019 J09L91 2232600 XACINE
4 2011  724 22989865 11jun2019  V9JAA  111230 MYCINE
```

Comment: This works for that data file, thank you! I have a similar problem for a similar file. Unfortunately your solution does not work for that, do you have an idea how I can de the same for the example data I put will edit in the main post?

Comment: That requires more work yes. But I'm not 100% sure I understand what the format is. Could you show what the table should look like with your new example? Does text always have "-quotes? Does text never have that? Do dates alwys not have "-quotes?